# File Size Validation on multiple upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a multiple file upload input. I'm trying to validate the size for each file. It works when I only use an if statement but when i use the for loop its not working. Any ideas why?

Thank you so much!

````
processFileAttachment: function (event) {
                var self = this,
                    pdfFile = event.target.files[0],
                    reader = new FileReader(),
                    fileAttachment = {};
    
                for (var i=0; i < pdfFile.length; i++){
                if (pdfFile[i].size > 5000000) 
                {
                    reader.addEventListener('load', function () {
                        fileAttachment = {
                            name: pdfFile.name,
                            contents: reader.result
                        }
                        self.options.fileModel.set('so_attachment', fileAttachment);
                        alert("Files must be less than 5MB");


                    });

                    reader.readAsDataURL(pdfFile);
                
            }
        }
            }
        });
    });```
````

Comment: In the line 3 have it as pdfFile = event.target.files

Comment: thanks @theekshanawj i followed that and added  reader.readAsDataURL(pdfFile[i])

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by theekshanawj I removed [0] and added reader.readAsDataURL(pdfFile[i])

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.